# MAC Visual Studio .Net 6 Blazor Hosting Error: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0

I am using Blazor wasm that connects to the "Netcore" server. I made this from the default template which has "Client", "Server", and "Shared". I use MAC Visual Studio 2022. I have tried to:

1. Close VS
2. Delete "bin" and "obj" folder from "Client" and "Server"
3. Clean all (clean solution)
4. Rebuild the app by right click the "Server" project and publishing to folder
5. Compress (zipped) the published folder
6. Upload the folder to my hosting provider with IIS (Interserver) and extract it

This is the error I got:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
> resource '' with computed SHA-256 integrity
> 'xV9SflNt5Ex5gP7OznQorlp2VkdJXkcAiopU+h5DRzY='. The resource has been
> blocked.

I have followed all the solutions I found online, including disabling the Blazor cache compression:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BlazorEnableCompression>false</BlazorEnableCompression>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But it does not work. Same error happens.

Comment: The error just indicates the integrity attribute of some script was not as excepted,Could you see which script get the error or could you provide the most simple project which could repeate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually from my hosting provider. There is a firewall rule which prevents `.dll` access. After I contacted the hosting provider support, they disable the firewall rule. Now it works fine.